# How can I refer to an awk field defined with an arbitrary expression?

Tags: awk

In shell scripting we have the `${name}` construct to explicitly specify a variable name and separate it from surrounding text.

In `awk`, I can refer to the fifth field with `$5` or the Nth field as pointed to by the variable N with `$N`.

What if I want to refer to the Nth+1 field?  If I use `$N+1` I'll get the content of the Nth field incremented by 1, which is not what I want.

I could set another variable `temp = N+1` and then reference `$temp`, but isn't there a way to specify the "Nth plus 1" field all in one go?

Or, for that matter, can I reference the Nth field where N is returned by a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just surround numbers with parentheses:

```
$ echo 1 3 5 7 | awk '{print $(1+3)}'
7
```

If you want to calculate field number with some function you don't need parentheses at all:

```
$ echo 1 3 5 7 | awk '{print $sqrt(16)}'
7
```

<sub>(Of course they don't hurt, so `$(sqrt(16))` works as well)</sub>